# Can I convert a Tex file into an equivalent Org file? If so, how?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I'm in the process of writing a whitepaper, and am about half-way through. I've just realized that it would be far simpler to write this in org-mode and export to latex/pdf than writing it directly in latex-mode. Is there any way I can convert the existing work into an org mode file? It would save a lot of work I'd have to do manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt as well that you will find a direct tool. You'll need to do some search'n'replace with one tool or the other.

What might help is to use [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) to convert your LaTeX to something closer to `org-mode` syntax like "markdown", "reStructuredText" or "MediaWiki" and then do your `query-replace-regexp` magic or write a small `sed` script.

Good luck on your journey!

**UPDATE:** Searching Google for ["convert latex to wiki"](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+latex+to+wiki) I found [this page](http://www.wikiwaves.org/index.php/Converting_Latex_to_Wiki) with a python script to convert LaTeX source code to Qwiki markup, maybe it gives you some inspiration.

**UPDATE:** As of 2018, [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options) supports org-mode as input and output format directly, [as pointed out by pkazmierczak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895264/2075630).

Comment: guess the best thing i can do is convert to markdown and work from there... 
thanks for telling me about pandoc though :)

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the latest version of Pandoc mode has a built-in support for Org-mode export.

[image]

Comment: how did you get the GUI version of Pandoc for OS X? I tried to install Pandoc on my Mac, but I only got a command-line version of pandoc.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be a little easier to convert the latex file to markdown using pandoc and then manually convert markdown to org-mode with a few query-replaces and emacs macros ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/uliw/l2org enables round-trip editing between latex and org-mode, i.e., when you collaborate with someone who uses latex

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a tool for your task, but you should be able to save many keystrokes with Emacs.

For many LaTeXisms such as quoted characters, try using `query-replace` and `query-replace-regexp` and see how far that gets you. For things that aren't easily solved with regular expressions, you may find keyboard macros useful.